# How to "unwind" include results on Sequelize?

Tags: javascript, sequelize.js

I have the following models on my system:User, Order, Payment and Scholarship. 
An user has many Orders, and an order has many payments. 
So, I want to get a user for each Order, like this:

UserId: 1, OrderId: 1, Payments: Array
UserId: 1, OrderId: 2, Payments: Array
UserId: 2, OrderId: 3, Payments: Array

I tried to use raw: true, and I got
UserId: 1, OrderId: 1, PaymentId: 1
UserId: 1, OrderId: 1, PaymentId: 2
UserId: 1, OrderId: 1, PaymentId: 3
UserId: 1, OrderId: 2, PaymentId: 4
UserId: 2, OrderId: 3, PaymentId: 5

And I don't need one user for each payment too.
I've tried to use limit on the payment model include, but then I get no payment data at all.

```
User.findAll({
            where: { delete: false },
            include: [
                {
                    model: Order,
                    include: [
                        {
                            model: Payment,
                            as: 'payments',
                        },
                        {
                            model: Scholarship,
                            as: 'scholarship',
                            include: ['institution', 'course'],
                        }]
                },
                {
                    model: Scholarship,
                    as: 'scholarship',
                    include: ['institution', 'course']
                }],
        });
```

I have already trid to use limit : 1 on the Payment model, but I get no payments at all, tried to use distinct too, but got syntax error.

Oh, and what I mean by unwind, is something I can do with Mongoose, was the best way I found to explain my problem.

I hope you guys understand, and sorry for my bad english.